# Check condition and retrieve data with single pass in the stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have some data:

```
    List<String> constData = new ArrayList<>();
    constData.add("data10115");
    constData.add("data8134");
    constData.add("data8933");
    constData.add("data8206");

    String strJSON = "[{\"type1\":\"data8933,data10115\",\"type2\":\"data8134,data8135,data9931\"},{\"type1\":\"data8204,data10115\",\"type2\":\"data8773,data8206,data9931\"}]";

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    List<Map<String, String>> mappedJSON = gson.fromJson(strJSON, new TypeToken<List<Map<String, String>>>(){}.getType());
```

Now I need to check if constData have some intersections with mappedJSON with some rules:

```
    System.out.println(
            mappedJSON.stream()
                .anyMatch(f -> f.entrySet().stream()
                        .allMatch(
                                e -> constData.stream()
                                        .anyMatch(CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(e.getValue().split(","))))::contains)
                        ))
    );
```

Now I want not just to check the condition, but also have the array of the interceptions. Is there any way to process this (check condition and retrieve intersections) with single pass?

I only have such variant:

```
   Set<String> result1 = new HashSet<>();
    for(Map<String, String> mapdata : mappedJSON) {
        Map<String, List<String>> mapNode = new HashedMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mapdata.entrySet()) {
            List<String> listNode = new ArrayList<>();
            constData.stream()
                    .filter(CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(entry.getValue().split(","))))::contains)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(l -> listNode.add(l));
            if(listNode.size() > 0) {
                mapNode.putIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), listNode);
            }
        }
        if(mapNode.entrySet().size() == mapdata.entrySet().size()) {
            result1.addAll(mapNode.entrySet().stream().map(x -> x.getValue()).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result1);
```

This code works as I need - I can check condition (set will be empty if condition is false) and get data with the single pass. But it's look "heavy")

Or I can use lambdas to check and after that to get data:

```
    if(
            mappedJSON.stream()
                .anyMatch(f -> f.entrySet().stream()
                        .allMatch(
                                e -> constData.stream()
                                        .anyMatch(CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(e.getValue().split(","))))::contains)
                        ))
    ) {

            List<String> result0 = new ArrayList<>();
            mappedJSON.stream()
                    .forEach(
                            m -> m.entrySet().stream()
                                    .forEach(
                                            s -> constData.stream()
                                                    .filter(CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s.getValue().split(","))))::contains)
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(l -> result0.add(l))
                                    )
                    );
            System.out.println(result0);
    }
```

This is also works, but here I need two passes.

Is there any other "light and beautiful" way?

More shorter version of my question:
Main logic expression is here:

```
   mappedJSON.stream().anyMatch(f -> f.entrySet().stream().allMatch(e -> constData.stream().anyMatch(Arrays.asList(s.getValue().split(","))::contains)))
```

Is there any "easy" way to get intersections from inner part of this expression (I mean this part: anyMatch(Arrays.asList(s.getValue().split(","))::contains)) ?

Comment: What’s the point of an expression like `CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(entry.getValue().split(","))))`?! You *know* that the collection is never `null`. Further, the result of `Arrays.asList(String[])` is already a `List<String>`, so why do you copy it to a new `ArrayList`? Just use `Arrays.asList(s.getValue().split(","))` and you’re done, writing less than a half code, and without needing a 3rd part library.

Comment: Further `.collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(l -> result0.add(l))` makes no sense. If you want to perform an action for each element, why do you collect into a `List` first. You can simply chain `forEach` to a Stream, however, since all you want is a `List` at the end, don’t nest 3! `forEach` calls just to `add` to a `List`. Use `flatMap` to compose a single stream, then use `.collect(Collectors.toList())` to get the result list.

Comment: If you want a list of all matches anywhere, there is no need to precheck at all. Collect the list and check whether it’s empty. That’s exactly fitting your desire to do it in one pass.

Comment: @Holger If you talk about second way with lambda - this not works without precheck, because in some cases result list will not be empty, but condition will not meet. This is the reason why I'm here.

Comment: It’s hard to recognize what your combination of `anyMatch`, `allMatch` and another `anyMatch` is supposed to do. I only take your words, that the check is supposed to determine *whether there are* intersections and the other code is supposed to *collect all* intersections. You described logic implies that “there are intersections” and “the list of intersections is not empty” are interchangeable conditions. If that’s not the case, either, your description is incomplete or your implementation is broken. But you didn’t mention such a problem, so your description is incomplete in either case.

Comment: More shorter version of my question:
Main logic expression is here: `mappedJSON.stream().anyMatch(f -> f.entrySet().stream().allMatch(e -> constData.stream().anyMatch(Arrays.asList(s.getValue().split(","))::contains)))`
Is there any "easy" way to get intersections from inner part of this expression (I mean this part: anyMatch(Arrays.asList(s.getValue().split(","))::contains)) ?